# Evaluating a limit expression

Tags: integration, limits

I am trying to show the  following identity but I am stuck.

$$\lim_{t\nearrow 1}(1-t)\int_0^t\frac{g(s)}{(1-s)^2}\,ds = g(1)$$
for any $g \in C[0,1]$. Apparently, the proof follows from L'Hopital's rule but I guess for that I first need to show 
$$\lim_{t\nearrow 1}\left\lvert\int_0^t\frac{g(s)}{(1-s)^2}\,ds \right\rvert= \infty$$
But that is not true since I can just take $g(s) = (1-s)^2$. But then the main result itself still holds. Is the hint about L'Hopital's rule wrong then? If so, how do I prove this result? I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use repeated integration by parts

Comment: @tired could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Doing ibp one time you will see that the announced result is generated. Repeating this procedure you will see that every newly generated part is vansihing at least $(1-t)(\log(1-t))$ as $t \rightarrow 1$

Comment: @tired how did you separate the integral into parts exactly? I am not asking about the procedure but the exact variables that you picked.

Comment: i would use $u(s)=g(s)$ and $v'(s)=\frac{1}{(1-s)^2}$

Comment: @tired how do you compute $du$. $g$ is not necessarily differentiable.

Comment: Urgh, i read $C^{\infty}$ ...but is the function at least pointwise differentiable? Then i think could generalize my argument. Where does this equation originally comes from?

Comment: Well actually I need the proof for the case where $g$ is nowhere differentiable because it will be the paths of Brownian motion later.

Comment: Ok my knowledge in brownian motion is rusty, but should partial integration then not be defined in an Ito-sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use Weierstrass approximation theorem, providing a polynomial $p(s)$ for which:
$$\forall s\in[0,1],\quad \left|g(s)-p(s)\right|\leq \varepsilon,\quad p'(0)=0, \tag{1}$$
then, for every $t\in[0,1)$,
$$(1-t)\left|\int_{0}^{t}\frac{g(s)}{(1-s)^2}\,ds-\int_{0}^{t}\frac{p(s)}{(1-s)^2}\,ds\right|\leq\varepsilon \tag{2}$$
and now we are allowed to use integration by parts:
$$ \int_{0}^{t}\frac{p(s)}{(1-s)^2}\,ds = \left.\frac{p(s)}{(1-s)}\right|_{0}^{t}-\int_{0}^{t}\frac{p'(s)}{(1-s)}\,ds\tag{3}$$
then multiply both sides by $(1-t)$ and take the limit as $t\to 1^-$ to prove that the original limit is arbitrarily close to $g(1)$. Notice that, since $p'(s)=s\cdot q(s)$:
$$\left|\int_{0}^{t}\frac{p'(s)}{(1-s)}\,ds\right|^2 = \left|\int_{0}^{t}\frac{s\cdot q(s)}{(1-s)}\,ds\right|^2\leq \int_{0}^{t}\frac{s\,ds}{(1-s)^2}\int_{0}^{t}s\cdot q(s)^2\,ds\tag{4}$$
hence:
$$\left|\int_{0}^{t}\frac{p'(s)}{(1-s)}\,ds\right|\leq\frac{C_q}{\sqrt{1-t}}.\tag{5}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one question. What do I do with the last term in (3) multiplied by $(1-t)$ as $t$ approaches 1 from the left?

Comment: @Calculon: you may bound the last piece by exploiting $p'(s)=s\cdot q(s)$ (since the derivative of $p(s)$ in zero is zero) and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, for instance.

Comment: Would you be able to write this explicitly in your answer if it won't be too much trouble? You are applying C-S to the last integral I am guessing. But then I get the term $\int_0^t\frac{(q(s))^2}{(1-s)^2}\,ds$. It is possible I am not applying the C-S in the way you intended.

Comment: @Calculon: it was the case, I was thinking to another way of applying the CS inequality. By the way, I have just added it to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let $G(t):=\int_0^t\frac{g(s)}{(1-s)^2}\,ds$. Note that $\lim_{t\nearrow 1}\frac{1}{1-t}=\infty$. Thus, by the [first fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part) and [L'Hospital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_form), we have (for $t\in (0,1)$)

$$\lim_{t\nearrow 1}(1-t)G(t) = \lim_{t\nearrow 1}\frac{G(t)}{1/(1-t)}=\lim_{t\nearrow 1}\frac{G^{'}(t)}{1/(1-t)^2}=\lim_{t\nearrow 1}\frac{g(t)/(1-t)^2}{1/(1-t)^2}=g(1)$$

Comment: Thanks but my question was about the conditions needed to apply L'Hopital's rule. Don't I first need to show that $G(t)$ goes to infinity as $t$ goes to 1 before I start taking derivatives?

Comment: @Calculon, I don't think you need to show that. Please see link for L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: Well I read it over a few times already but it doesn't apply to cases where the denominator goes to infinity and the numerator does whatever. Numerator has to go to infinity as well.

Comment: @Calculon, Do you know a proof of L'Hospital's rule? On the linked page, in the stated proof, it is noted that the numerator being divergent is not used in the proof. It also states, immediately following the statement of the rule for a divergent numerator and denominator, that a divergent numerator is not necessary for the rule's applicability. Please re-read the link.

Comment: I didn't read the proof. I just read the statement of the theorem. I will look into it, thanks.

Comment: Case 2 indeed covers the case where the denominator goes to infinity and the numerator does not have to go to infinity.

Comment: @Calculon, is there any part of my answer that still does not address any of your concerns?

Comment: No it is really fine. Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Calculon ;) you are welcome